# Magento 2 Completely cancel/remove module

Tags: magento2, module, hard-delete

I installed some extensions manually some time ago, without composer.
Now I'd like to delete them.

> Is there a way to permanently delete them?

Now they are disabled. Especially some extensions that are like **"Backend Shared Extension"**

I enclose some text written by the removal form guide:

> Important: If you are using other WeltPixels extensions make sure not to remove the **'Backend'** shared extension as is used by the rest of WeltPixel installed extensions. WeltPixel extensions it is safe to uninstall and remove also the 'Backend' extension.

Thank you.

Magento 2.2 CE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already run the following commands:

```
php bin/magento module:disable <ExtensionProvider_ExtensionName> --clear-static-content
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And removed its files in

> app/code/{ExtensionProvider}

The last thing to do is delete at least its data in **`setup_module`** table

And in the shared Backend extension, you can safely delete it as well assuming that you are not using other extensions that have a dependency on it.